# excel query for Grouping and finding max value

Tags: excel

I want to find the max value within a group (group by:Column A , max value : column E) and copy entire raw to a next sheet in excel.

```
A-B-C-D-E

1-10-4-2-5.491

1-10-5-2-5.8

1-20-4-3-4.498

2-30-5-3-6.663

2-30-6-4-8.205

2-10-4-5-8.562

3-10-5-6-7.026

3-30-7-2-10.665

3-30-8-2-8.472

4-10-4-1-4.489

4-10-5-1-5.491

4-25-7-3-0.816
```

My expectation is to get the output as below in another sheet.

```
1-10-5-2-5.8

2-10-4-5-8.562

3-30-7-2-10.665

4-10-5-1-5.491
```

Please suggest a solution with excel functions and formulas other than pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=MAX(IF(A1$A50=A2,E$1:E$50))
```

The important thing here is that this is an array formula, so instead of pressing just Enter, you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not using entire column references within an array formula. Unlike e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), array formulas are forced to calculate over all cells within the range passed, whether those cells are technically beyond the last-used cell in that range or not.

Comment: @XORLX  I didn't know that. I corrected my mistake :)

Comment: @XORLX Can you comment on OP's question to accept answer if it was useful? Seems like a throwaway account though.

Comment: Apologies - still not that familiar with the workings of Stackoverflow. What precisely do you want me to do?

Comment: @XORLX I meant the OP left without accepting any answer or further discussing. But hopefully this helps some one else in the future.

Comment: I see. Oh dear. It does appear to the case. Frustrating for you, no doubt.